# How to generate a .csv file from rythm

Tags: rythm

I currently have code to generate an xml file using a rythm template. I am wondering how i can use the same code to generate a .csv file? Is there a way to do it?

please advise.

Comment: Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use csv format to create the template file, and better give it a name `xxx.csv`.

Checkout the full demo at https://github.com/greenlaw110/Rythm/tree/master/samples/demo_fo_SO_150529

You can run it with `mvn compile exec:java` if you download the whole demo to you local disk

Comment: Thanks for the link. My Question is more on - if you have to iterate through a list and show all the content, how can we do it with .csv file?

Comment: Can you please guide me on how i can iterate through the list while generating a csv file?

Comment: see http://rythmengine.org/doc/template_guide.md#flow-control and http://rythmengine.org/doc/directive.md#for and practice at http://fiddle.rythmengine.org/#/editor/976408dec0074a8e8c1f7364eab04e20

Comment: I played with fiddle and got a hang on how to do looping. However what I wanted to achieve is : given the headers Reqname, StartTime, endTime, Result, Error_code, Error_message I would like to generate .csv file. In my use case, there could be multiple error_code and error_messages. For eg: if there are 3 errors, the headers should include error_code1, error_message1, error_code2, error_message2, error_code3, error_message3.  I have created a sample .csv format. When I run the file, I am seeing the for loop also as part of the file generation. Can you please help me on how I can do this?

Comment: Can someone please show me an example on how i can generate csv file using rythm template? I need it asap. please help me.

Comment: I've updated the demo app with loop in csv template: https://github.com/greenlaw110/Rythm/blob/master/samples/demo_fo_SO_150529/src/main/resources/templates/MyTemplate.csv

Comment: Thanks for providing an example. It was helpful. However when I render my template, I see the output as follows. I see headers and data are coming in the same row. And the Header is missing one column "name". ,email,addressTester1,123,myAddress Tester1,123,myAddress Tester1,123,myAddress Tester1,123,myAddress Tester1,123,myAddress. Can you please help me on how we can solve this?

Comment: Can you please help me on why I dont see the first header and why the headers and first line of data are coming on the same line?   This is breaking my app on storing the file as .csv.  Kindly help.

Comment: Hello Green, can you please help me. I am currently stuck with this issue, Appreciate if you can please guide.